# How to display weights/frequency of each word in wordcloud?

Tags: r, ggplot2, word-cloud

I have created a `wordcloud` and, have used `wordcloud()` and `ggplot()`. I am unable to add the word frequencies to respective words in the cloud. I want the labels to appear in a single size and not in the size/weight of the associated word.

Can somebody help me add the labels? I have checked similar links:
[How to display frequency in wordcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298725/how-to-display-frequency-in-wordcloud)

But I want the labels to be of standard size.

[image]

Sample code:

```
library(wordcloud)

    wordcloud(BO$keywords, BO$bo, min.freq =1, scale=c(2.5,1), random.order = FALSE,
               rot.per = 0,
              colors = pal)+
      geom_text_wordcloud_area(shape = "square", eccentricity = 2)+geom_text_repel(segment.size = 5, force = 1)


    ggplot(BO, aes(label = keywords, size = bo), scale=c(6,5), min.freq = 1) +
      geom_text_wordcloud(shape = "square", eccentricity = 2,  area_corr=FALSE) +
      scale_size_area(max_size = 6) +
      theme_minimal()+
      facet_wrap(~bo)+
      scale_color_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend adding the image of your code so users are best able to help you!

Comment: Thanks. I cant add image due to my low reputation:
![Sample image](https://blog.polleverywhere.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/WORD-CLOUD-TAGCROWD-2-1.jpg)

Comment: Can somebody in SO community help me with this? I still don't have the solution to display frequencies in wordcloud in a standard font size in R? Can this be done in Python? It is possible in Tableau but it has other limitations.